# Using the boundary states, is there a precise way to write down a planar open string multi-loop amplitude as a closed string tree amplitude?

Tags: string-theory

The only explicit computation I have seen is the planar 1-loop one, but there should be a way to write the multi-loop case in terms of boundary states as well.